# An uncaught Exception was encountered when i click on forget password to send email

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am getting this error

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
> Type: Error
>
> Message: Call to undefined method CI_Form_validation::substr()
>
> Filename: /home/thedevel/public_html/esports/new/system/libraries/Form_validation.php
>
> Line Number: 1065
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /home/thedevel/public_html/esports/new/application/controllers/Login.php
> Line: 495
> Function: run
>
> File: /home/thedevel/public_html/esports/new/index.php
> Line: 275
> Function: require_once

here is the code of

Filename: /home/thedevel/public_html/esports/new/system/libraries/Form_validation.php

Line Number: 1065

```
public function valid_email($email) {
        if (function_exists('idn_to_ascii') && defined('INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46') && $atpos = strpos($email, '@')) {
            $email = self::substr($email, 0, ++$atpos) . idn_to_ascii(self::substr($email, $atpos), 0, INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46);
        }
        return (bool) filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    }
```

Please help

Comment: Your question doesn't even contain a question. We need more debugging information. My guess is that `self::substr` doesn't exist which is probably what the error message is telling you. Is there `substr` in that class? Should it be there? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure with the self::substr ? It should be this :

```
public function valid_email($email) {
        if (function_exists('idn_to_ascii') && defined('INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46') && $atpos = strpos($email, '@')) {
            $email = substr($email, 0, ++$atpos) . idn_to_ascii(substr($email, $atpos), 0, INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46);
        }
        return (bool) filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    }
```